# How to receive information from container view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get sticky header and change only body part of View Controller so i use Container View as body. 
[this is my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Afbkt.png)
i have no problem updating "HomeViewController" title from "ViewController2" using delegation method:

```swift
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var headerTitleLabel: UILabel!

    // MARk: Properties

    // MARK: view life cycles
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let nav = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
            let vc = nav.viewControllers.first as? ViewController2 {
            vc.delegate = self

        }
    }
}

extension HomeViewController: ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate {
    func setHeader(title: String) {
        self.headerTitleLabel.text = title   
    }
}
```

```swift
import UIKit

protocol ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate: class {
    func setHeader(title: String)
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    weak var delegate: ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate!

    // MARK: View Life Cycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate.setHeader(title: "hello friend")
    }

}
```

on "ViewController2" is "Button1" which shows "ViewController3" on click and now i don't know how to update "HomeViewController" title from ViewController3, so i need your help here.

I think this is not the best way of doing sticky header and if you have any better idea i would also appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should just be able to inject the delegate down from VC2 to VC3, aka something like

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    weak var delegate: ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate!

    // the function called when button 1 is pressed
    func presentVC3() {
        // I assuming your code doesn't look like this since you seem to be using
        // storyboard segue's but the idea is the same
        let vc3 = VC3()
        vc3.delegate = self.delegate
        ...
    }

}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    weak var delegate: ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate!
```

But this feels wrong. 
I am not sure how VC2 is "showing" VC3, but perhaps a better idea would be to have VC2 inform the `HomeViewController` via a new method in `ReceiveDataFromContainerViewDelegate` that it should replace the view controller in the container view. when `HomeViewController` is creating the VC3 to put in the container view, it can then set the delegate in VC3 the same way you do for VC2.

Alternatively, you can also use [Notification Center](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter) to listen to a custom notification that can send the new header.. You would add on observer on `HomeViewController` and broadcast the notification with the header in any of the other VCs, but in general you should avoid Notification Center where possible since it can lead to unexpected behaviors down the road and code with a lot of Notification Center becomes so hard to work with and reason about (it's usually a lazy solution, but can have its place).